# Склейка данных в представлении

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Хочу вывести в @Html.TextBoxFor ФИО менеджера, но не знаю как это сделать.

Есть ModelView такого вида

```
public class SupplierDetailView
    {
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedServicesIds { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }

    }
```

Эти данные я вывожу в сплывающее окно. У одного постановщика может быть много менеджеров и тд. Так сделано в моей модели.

```
  public class Supplier
    {
        [Display(Name = "SupplierID")]
        [Key]
        public int SupplierID { set; get; }

        [Display(Name = "Коммерческое название")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        public string Name { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<Manager> Managers { get; set; }

    }
```

Сокращенно, но принцип будет вам понятен, я думаю. И ниже переведена модель менеджера.

```
  public class Manager
        {
            [Display(Name = "ManagerID")]
            [Key]
            public int ManagerID { set; get; }

            [Display(Name = "Имя")]
            [StringLength(250)]
            [Column(TypeName = "char")]
            public string FirstName { set; get; }

            [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
            [StringLength(200)]
            [Column(TypeName = "char")]
            public string SecondName { set; get; }

            [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
            [StringLength(200)]
            [Column(TypeName = "char")]
            public string MiddleName { set; get; }
}
```

Собираю данные в модель на контроллере и при запросе по id передаю на редактирование в сплывающее окно.

```
  [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                var supplier = db.Suppliers.Find(id);

                var model = new SupplierDetailView
                {
                    Supplier = supplier
                };


                return PartialView("_Supplier_Edit", model);

            }
```

В итоге по менеджеру делаю так

```
 <div class="field">
            <label>ФИО</label>
            @foreach (var manager in Model.Supplier.Managers)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => manager.Name)
            }
        </div>

 <div class="field">
            <label>ФИО</label>
            @foreach (var manager in Model.Supplier.Managers)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => manager.FirstName)
            }
        </div>
```

Но это бред , как мне объединить два поля в одно? Склеить данные и вывести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хотите использовать во вьюмодели контракт (ДТО) то самый простой способ добавить свойство (напр. FullName) в тип Manager, задекорировать его атрибутом Ignore и в его сеттер и геттер зашить логику установки и чтения значений FirstName, SecondName, MiddleName соответственно:

```
public class Manager
{
    [Display(Name = "ManagerID")]
    [Key]
    public int ManagerID { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string FirstName { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string SecondName { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string MiddleName { set; get; }

    [Ignore]
    public string FullName 
    { 
        get
        {
            return $"{this.SecondName} {this.FirstName}  {this.MiddleName}";
        }
        set
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(value, "(?<secondname>\w+)\s(?<firstname>\w+)\s(?<middlename>\w+)");
            this.FirstName = match.Groups["firstname"].Value;
            this.SecondName = match.Groups["secondname"].Value;
            this.MiddleName = match.Groups["middlename"].Value;
        } 
    }
}
```